# How to align rectangles adjacent?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment

[image]

I'd like to make the selected rectangles all vertically adjacent (no gaps), not overlapping.  Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found it, I had to use the spacing 
[image]